# How to draw an SFML shape on the intersection with a polygon

Tags: c++, sfml

Say I have a polygon (i. e. an array of 2d points). What is the easiest way to draw any `sf::Shape` but only affecting pixels contained within that polygon?

I have drawn my polygons with sf::ConvexShape. And I want to draw mostly circles on those polygons.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches.

The first is to use **stencil operations**. This adds a step to the graphics pipeline that compares the stencil value of fragments you are drawing with. The idea would be that you draw your polygon with stencil value 1 and then draw circles with the stencil comparison function set to "equals 1".

The second approach is to use **alpha blending**. This step happens later in the graphics pipeline, where the final pixel value in a framebuffer is determined by combining the source and destination alpha values somehow. The idea here would be that you start from an image with alpha=0 and draw your polygon with alpha=1. If you then draw your circles with the alpha blending operation set to "destination alpha" you would end up with an image where your polyon target has pixels with the correct color value and alpha=1, and outside of that polygon would have the correct color value but alpha=0, hence not showing up when this image is further rendered or blended.

For both approaches you will want to set up a separate `sf::RenderTexture` and render your polygon and circles into that first, then draw the underlying texture to your screen (either as a full-screen image or a part of it).

The alpha blending approach is completely supported by SFML, for the stencil approach you need to do some low-level OpenGL calls, namely:

```
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, ~0);
glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE);

// Draw your polygon to the render texture here

glStencilOp(GL_EQUAL, 1, ~0);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);

// Draw your circles here

glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

// Render the sf::RenderTexture to screen
```